# Table Per Hierarchy based on fields in the Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an entity which has a navigation property. I would like to define derived entities from the base entity using a field in the navigation property as the discriminator.  Is this possible. I could not find a way to do this in the designer.

Comment: don't think it's possible. maybe you could add some detail on your entities, what your trying to achieve and we can try and think of a workaround. think about it - can you have a "conditional FK"? because that's what your attempting to do. doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible with navigation property. It should be possible to map two tables in 1:1 relation into single entity. You can try to combine it with table per hiearchy mapping. I'm interested if it works but i don't have chance to try it now.